# A way to automatically hide inactive windows in XP (only the active window & desktop are visible)

Tags: windows-xp

Is there any way, in Windows XP, to make it so that I see **only the window I'm working in** over the desktop, so that **all other windows are hidden**?

I have a large screen, and it gets quite cluttered when I'm programming. It would be nice to **hide all the clutter**, but a maximized window is often too big to read easily.

I am looking for a solution that will **automatically hide** any inactive windows, so that I can use alt-tab to choose the window I want, and **the window that was active will disappear when I select a new one**.

Update: **MinimOther** by Skrommel (http://www.brothersoft.com/minimother-101553.html) does exactly what I want, but it doesn't work with some of the main programs I use.

Comment: I don't think that this can be accomplished easily, as it totally contradicts the paradigm of windows (imho).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might try [TransOther](http://www.donationcoder.com/Software/Skrommel/index.html#TransOther), which makes all windows but the active one transparent.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I tried it and set transparency=0, and it has the desired effect. However, there is a noticeable delay, and it doesn't work on Komodo Edit, which is the main program I would like to hide.

Comment: You might try to raise the question on their forums - the author is a very productive guy.

Comment: In going to the forums I discovered MinimOther by the same guy. It is exactly what I'm looking for. Unfortunately, it won't work with a couple of other programs that I totally depend on (NoteTab Pro and FlashFXP). Komodo Edit works perfectly, however. I left a note on the forum.

Answer (score 0):

Windows-D, and then alt-tab or click only the application that you want.

Comment: Sorry, the question wasn't clear -- I'm looking for a way to do this automatically, so that the permanent state of my computer is one active window at a time.

Comment: Have you thought about a different approach? Maybe Virtual Desktops? http://news.cnet.com/8301-13880_3-9902461-68.html